# How to find the isometry group of space-time?

Tags: spacetime, symmetry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

I am given the next pseudometric:

$$
ds^2=dt^2-\frac{r^2+a^2 \cos^2 \theta}{r^2+a^2}dr^2-(r^2+a^2)\sin^2 \theta d\phi^2-(r^2+a^2\cos^2 \theta)d\theta^2.
$$

How to find the isometry group for such space-time? Mostly I'm interested in a general approach.

Answer (score 1):

An isometry group $G$ of a manifold consists of bijective maps which preserve distance, defined by the metric. Now, the infinitesimal generators are usually the Killing fields $X$ for which,$^\dagger$

$$\mathcal L_X g = 0$$

i.e. the Lie derivative of the metric along $X$ vanishes. Assuming the Levi-Civita connection and metric compatibility, we have that,

$$\nabla_\mu X_\nu + \nabla_\nu X_\mu = 0.$$

Solving this system of differential equations, one can extract $X$ and thus the generators of the isometries. Now, to find the finite transformations, one must solve,

$$\frac{dx^\mu(\lambda)}{d\lambda} = X^\mu(x(\lambda))$$

which is to find the integral curves $x^\mu$ of the Killing field, $X$. From the finite transformations, or even sometimes from the infinitesimal generators in some obvious cases or with some massaging, one may be able to deduce the isometry group or at least a subset of isometries.

---

There are some general results about isometry groups of manifolds or groups of motions as they may be called. The integrability conditions,

$$\mathcal L_X R = 0, \quad \mathcal L_X (\nabla_{i_1} \dots \nabla_{i_N} R) = 0, N = 1,2, \dots$$

and the constraints having rank $q$ for an $n$-dimensional manifold constrain the maximal group $G_r$ of motions to have $r = \frac12 n(n+1) - q$ parameters. It can also be said that the maximal order of a group $G_r$ of conformal transformations is $r = \frac12 n(n+1)(n+2)$.

I would recommend reading, *Exact Solutions of the Einstein Field Equations*, as the authors do a remarkable job of outlining many points of interests and methods of spacetimes not taught in standard courses, and particularly with respect to isometries.

For your problem, you should also note the Ricci scalar, $R$ is a function of only $\theta$ and $r$ unsurprisingly, which motivates finding solutions for which $X_\theta = X_r = 0.$

---

$\dagger$ The Killing condition itself comes from the fact that if I perform a diffeomorphism,

$$x^\mu \to \xi^\mu(x)$$

then infinitesimally, the metric changes as $g \to g + \mathcal L_\xi g$ and we want $\mathcal L_\xi g = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some some shortcuts, but the bottom line is what are the vectors X that satisfy the Killing Equation, JamalS's second equation. Brute force, write an arbitrary vector and solve the equations. The constraints on R in the second part to this answer may help. His reference may have shortcuts.

The metric does not seem totally unfamiliar, it might have a conformal symmetry to a simpler metric. Note that a is the only free parameter, with a=0 being Minkowski spacetime in spherical coordinates. By the way since none of the metric components depends on t, it is an isometry, and the components of the vector X you can assume are independent of t.

Not a solution, but hope this helps looking for it